# Which folders are in /dev/sde3?

Tags: filesystem, disk, disk-usage, df, du

How to see which folders are in `/dev/sde3` ?

```
df -h
/dev/sde3                              39G   32G  4.8G  87% /
```

Doing:

```
cd /
sudo du -d 1 -h | sort -hr
```

Also shows me folders like:

```
/dev/sde4                             167G  140G   19G  89% /home
```

which are in another location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-x` option of `du` to exclude other file systems:

```
sudo du -d 1 -h -x | sort -hr
```